# Access html elements in ASP.NET C# Web Forms / from Site.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have Site.master where I have all my layout for the Website.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>
```

Among other stuff,it includes something as simple as a button, or other elements, example:

```
<button runat="server" id="logoutButton" onserverclick="logout" class="dropdown-item" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="ft-power"></i>Logout</button>
```

Now I have another WebForm in a Folder named Reports

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CompanyReports.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports_CompanyReports" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

I want to change lets say background of the button (which is in the master page) from the WebForm CompanyReports.aspx from code behind
I am not able to do so with the following:
`logoutButton.Style["background-color"] = "red";`
It gives me error that the logoutButton does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `FindControl` in the Master to locate Controls.

```
var button = Master.FindControl("logoutButton") as HtmlControl;
button.Style["background-color"] = "red";
```

Or as one-liner

```
((HtmlControl)Master.FindControl("logoutButton")).Style["background-color"] = "red";
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Indeed it works.
What about this part: onserverclick="logout" which is still in the site master
It gives me when I try to access it from a child page: 
CS1061: 'site_master' does not contain a definition for 'logout' and no accessible extension method 'logout' accepting a first argument of type 'site_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If the `logout` method is in the master.cs file it will work.